# Sharepoint Total Disk Space

Tags: storage, space-usage

I have been using a company SharePoint website and would like to know it's total disk space size.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Clauber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on your level of access to SharePoint as well as to the server that your SharePoint installation is running on.

If you have Site Collection Administration privileges you can go to **Site Settings | Site Collection Administration | Storage Metrics** to find out how much disk space is being occupied by the site. Though this doesn't give you a total for the amount of disk space available (*a bit of math you could ball park and figure out how much has been quoted by the Farm Admins*).

If you have actual access to the server itself then you would just see how much hard drive space has been allotted. Like you normally would in Windows. Keep in mind though that there is a clear difference between your storage on the server and the SQL content databases (*which ideally would be on a separate server*). Most items that are uploaded to a Library in SharePoint are stored in the SQL content database, and not in the SharePoint Hive.

Comment: If I navigate to Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Storage Metric to find out how much disk space is being occupied by the site, then would this step give me the space details occupied by content database or else? Please let me know... Thanks.

Comment: Yes, content database.

Comment: If I use sharepoint designer to estimate the total amount of space based on the now occupied and the percentage shown, is this the content database space also?

Comment: Yes. Only time you will get disk space for your core SharePoint installation is by remote accessing or logging into your server / VM. Same can be said for where you have your SQL Server instance running.